# How to get original string back in CryptoJS using TripleDES?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs, tripledes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt in JavaScript using [TripleDES.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#DES,_Triple_DES). Here is my code snippet:

**Encryption Method:**

```
encrypt_string = function (plainData) {

   var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(plainData, "My Secret Key");

   alert("Encrypted: " + encrypted);

}
```

**Decryption Method:**

```
decrypt_string = function (cipherData) {

   var decrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(cipherData, "My Secret Key");

   alert("Decrypted: " + decrypted);

}
```

While passing `plainData` as `Gokul Nath`, to `encrypt_string()`, the alert message shows:

```
U2FsdGVkX1/huVhh9IQhJF72gcs26f1l0+hNSsWEXsc=
```

While passing `cipherData` as `U2FsdGVkX1/huVhh9IQhJF72gcs26f1l0+hNSsWEXsc=`, to `decrypt_string()`, the alert message shows:

```
476f6b756c204e617468
```

***Question:*** How to get the original plain data while decrypting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`476f6b756c204e617468` is the hex representation of the original string:

```
47 6f 6b 75 6c 20  4e 61 74 68
G  o  k  u  l  |/  N  a  t  h
               |
               +-> this is a space
```

You can use something like `decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1)` to get the string value, as per:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/tripledes.js"></script>
<script>
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt("Gokul Nath", "My Secret Key");
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(encrypted, "My Secret Key");
    alert("Decrypted: " + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1));
</script>
```

which gives:

[image]